# Matplotlib Stacked Histogram Bin Width

Tags: python, matplotlib

When creating a stacked histogram in Matplotlib I noticed that the bin widths shrink. In this simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

#Create histograms and plots
fig = plt.figure()
gs = matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)
h1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
h2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1])

x = np.random.normal(0, 5, 500)
y = np.random.normal(0, 20, 500)

bins = np.arange(-60,60, 5)

h1.hist([x, y], bins=bins, stacked=True)
h2.hist(x, bins=bins, alpha=1)
h2.hist(y, bins=bins, alpha=0.5)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
filename = 'sample.pdf'
plt.savefig(filename)
```

I get the following output:

[image]

Notice that the histogram on the left has spacing between each bin even though both the left and right histograms are using the same bins.

Is there a way to correct this behavior? I would like the histogram on the left to use the full bin widths such that neighboring bins share an edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first argument of a `ax.hist`-call is a list of lists (or a 2d numpy-array or a combination of the two) it will automatically make the bins smaller. The `rwidth` parameter of the `ax.hist`-call is the parameter that determines the bin-width. Setting it to 1 will do what you want it to do:

`h1.hist([x, y], bins=bins, stacked=True, rwidth=1)`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you know why the default behavior is to shrink the bins?